# Heroku App crashing when calling shopify graphql api in forloop

Tags: php, heroku, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I have created a Heroku app that uses Graphql API on Shopify, on a product level, it has no problem returning the data, but on variants, since this is where I need to have the mutation, I added the graphql code inside for loop and it crash, please let me know how I can improve it, or how I improved it so it won't crash. by the way, I used PHP if that helps

This is the product level graphql

[image]

This is where I add the for loop and mutation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is nearly impossible to answer. You provide no debugging clues. Your query is a bit strange as you ask for only half the variants, (first: 50) with no effort the get the last 50. A smart organization might be:

- ask for the variants and the metafield you want directly in the query
- use cursors to page through the variants.

There is no need to make API calls per variant here. You can of course, but why bother.

Log your responses. Shopify will tell you what error you making in GQL. Without your logs, no one can help you.

Comment: Regarding the error, it is not the shopify that has an error though, it seems like that for loop (variants) that i have is the one causing the heroku app to crash. Regarding the variants first:50, i just used that, cause the highest number of variants we have on the record has 30 so i thought it doesn't needed to add cursor

Comment: Your struggles will continue if you don't master the basics. A loop with cursors is easy enough to learn, and will benefit you immensely as most real-world situations don't involve lucky guessing, like 30. 

Debugging is hard. As I said, you provide nothing for anyone to help you with, so your post here will likely rot until you do provide better information to the community that can help you!